# Webp image loading Issue. Its show Code in Browser instead of showing images

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu, server

i have used laravel-medialibrary and it convert user uploaded image to webp and it display fine when image called via img src [see here](https://lawyers974.com/).

But if we open that image in new tab it shows code like
RIFFH$��WEBPVP8 <$��0º�*ôw>m6–I$"¬¤#2Y9

and so on ... [see here](https://lawyers974.com/storage/148/conversions/beautiful-pregnant-belly-thumb.webp)

It's a ubuntu server with apache.

is anything on server configuration because its perfect in local environment and work perfectly if uploaded in cpanel servers

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. The webp file works perfectly fine on both your links. Try empty the browser cache.

Comment: I do also see them correctly, I see all images. Try using another browser, or open the same pages in an incognito tab (it will have no cache and some extensions installed by you, disabled)

Comment: yes, I checked in different browsers chrome, firefox, and even in mobile browsers i seed code still. see this link https://lawyers974.com/storage/148/conversions/beautiful-pregnant-belly-thumb.webp

Comment: I too see the image just fine. You seem to be using Cloudflare which may be holding a cache specific to you (or your region). Try loading a different URL like e.g. https://lawyers974.com/storage/148/conversions/beautiful-pregnant-belly-thumb.webp?abc=def (the query string is for cache busting)

Comment: issue fixed when I changed image driver to imagick from gd

Answer (score 1):

issue fixed when I changed image driver to imagick from gd